# How to Securely Store a Non-End-User Generated Decryption Key in Android Keystore?

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore

I'm working on an Android application where I need to securely store a decryption key. This key is not generated by the end-user, it is pre-defined key that my application will use to decrypt certain data so the users can access it offline.

My question is how can I store this key securely to a keystore. If it is passed from API, it could be exposed through man in the middle. If the key is hard coded it can easily be found after decompiling the app.

What are the recommended methods to store this key, or it is not possible for such cases.

Comment: AFAIK (but i might be wrong) even if you use keystore to safely store this, you would still need the server to send the decrypt key once to the client. An easier way but still quite protected is to just save the key in NDK. I don't think it is good to save sensitive information locally anyway.